# Square roots and powers

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation

This is a rather silly question.
In what order does one evaluate a combination of powers and fractional powers?

I have the question phrased:

> $\sqrt{ 1/4^2 }$ OR ${ 1/4 }$? Which is greater?

I answered that it cannot be determined, because the ${ 1/4^2 }$ could be evaluated first and then the square root, yielding $\pm 1/4$. I understand it could also be the multiplication of exponents, yielding **+1/4**.

Which of these is correct?

Comment: $\sqrt{1/4^2}=\sqrt{1/16}=1/4=RHS$

Comment: Why not the negative value? $\sqrt{ 1/16 } = \pm1/4$

Comment: $\sqrt{n}:n\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ should be greater than or equal to zero

Comment: That's a different case, like when you're comparing with $x$ and $y$ when $x=\sqrt{16}$ and $y=2^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sqrt x$ means, by definition, the **positive** number $r$ with $r^2=x$.

EDIT: make that, the **non-negative** number $r$ with $r^2=x$. Wouldn't want to leave out zero.

Comment: Yes, $x^2=16$ has two solutions. One of them is $\sqrt{16}$, the other is $-\sqrt{16}$. We do it this way because we want $\sqrt x$ to be a **function**, to have a unique value for each input $x$.

Comment: I just realized that myself. I've been really stupid. Thanks. :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson  A reliable source who claims that zero has no square root... Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

Here $(\sqrt \frac {1}{4^2})$ gives us only $\frac {1}{4}$ as root function has an absolute value associated with it .

Remember : $\sqrt {x^2}$ means, by definition, the **absolute value of x ** number

answer : both aree same